# Глючит графический редактор для построения макетов

Tags: android, android-studio

Обновил AndroidStudio до 3.4.2  и перешёл на androidx. Начал жестко глючить графический редактор для построения макетов. Вкладки Design и Preview ничего не отображают, несмотря на то, что элементы в XML есть. Переключение AppTheme в настройках редактора помогаю, но не всегда. Если выйти из студии и заново войти - всё работает. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Есть ли какое-нибудь решение помимо перезапуска?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может конечно совпадение, но однажды я сделал 

File >> Invalidate Caches / Restarts и больше я с таким не сталкивался.

Comment: Не помогло Invalidate Caches / Restarts